# using WriteBatch inside for loop gives error

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have around 27,000 documents that I had like to write into my firestore collecton.

In order to do so, I use WriteBatch and I break it every 500 documents.

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A write batch can no longer be used after commit() has been called.
```

The code im using is:

```
private void addData2DB(ArrayList<String> titles, ArrayList<String> authors, ArrayList<String> publishers, ArrayList<String> genres, ArrayList<String> pages) {
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    WriteBatch batch = db.batch();
    double counter = 1.0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= titles.size(); i++) {

        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        String title = titles.get( i );

        String[] TitleWords = title.split( "\\s+" );

        if (!title.isEmpty()) {
            String docID = db.collection( "GeneratingID" ).document().getId();

            data.put( "bookAuthor", authors.get( i ) );
            data.put( "bookTitle", titles.get( i ) );
            data.put( "genre", genres.get( i ) );
            data.put( "pages", pages.get( i ) );
            data.put( "publishedBy", publishers.get( i ) );

            DocumentReference dr = db.collection( "BooksDB" ).document( docID );
            batch.set( dr, data );
        }

        if ((double) i / 500 == counter) {
            batch.commit();
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
    }

}
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Create batch instanse over again in statement if, just after line batch.commit(). Using counter of double type is not a good idea. Comparison double value to the division result is not give any garantee.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `WriteBatch batch = db.batch();` inside your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: A write batch can no longer be used after commit() has been called.

Most likely because your code doesn't wait for the first commit to complete. To write 500 documents to Firestore, takes some time, as it's an asynchronous operation. So you get the above error because a batch object can't be modified again after you call commit().

So you need to wait until the operation completes before adding new write operations to the batch and call again "commit()".